# data is not posted in $_POST variable using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Im having a problem in one of my script. Server is running in php, and im using AJAX to post data. Here is my script.

PHP script:

```
<?php

include './connConf.php';

if (isset($_POST['pStr'])){
    $preStr=$_POST['pStr'];
    $query="SELECT * FROM advisory WHERE projname in (SELECT projname FROM advisorydata WHERE prefixStr LIKE '%$preStr')";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $num=mysql_numrows($result);
    if ($num > 0){
        echo "<font style=\"font-size:12px\" color=\"#FF6820\" face=\"Century Gothic\"><b>Search Result :</b></font><br><br>";
        for ($x=0;$x<$num;$x+=1){
            echo "<font style=\"font-size:12px\" color=\"#FFFFFF\" face=\"Century Gothic\">Project Name:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</font><font style=\"font-size:11px\" color=\"#C0FFFF\" face=\"Century Gothic\"><b>".mysql_result($result,$x,"projname")."</b></font><br>";
            echo "<font style=\"font-size:12px\" color=\"#FFFFFF\" face=\"Century Gothic\">APMS ID:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</font><font style=\"font-size:11px\" color=\"#C0FFFF\" face=\"Century Gothic\"><b>".mysql_result($result,$x,"apmsid")."</b></font><br>";
            echo "<font style=\"font-size:12px\" color=\"#FFFFFF\" face=\"Century Gothic\">Prefix/es:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</font><font style=\"font-size:11px\" color=\"#C0FFFF\" face=\"Century Gothic\"><b>".mysql_result($result,$x,"projprefix")."</b></font><br>";
            echo "<font style=\"font-size:12px\" color=\"#FFFFFF\" face=\"Century Gothic\">Usage Type:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</font><font style=\"font-size:11px\" color=\"#C0FFFF\" face=\"Century Gothic\"><b>".mysql_result($result,$x,"usagetype")."</b></font><br>";
            echo "<font style=\"font-size:12px\" color=\"#FFFFFF\" face=\"Century Gothic\">Rate:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</font><font style=\"font-size:11px\" color=\"#C0FFFF\" face=\"Century Gothic\"><b>".mysql_result($result,$x,"projrate")."</b></font><br>";
            echo "<font style=\"font-size:12px\" color=\"#FFFFFF\" face=\"Century Gothic\">Offer Details:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</font><font style=\"font-size:11px\" color=\"#C0FFFF\" face=\"Century Gothic\"><b>".mysql_result($result,$x,"offerdetails")."</b></font><br><br>";
        }
    }else{
        echo "<font style=\"font-size:12px\" color=\"#FFFFFF\" face=\"Century Gothic\">No results found ...</font>";
    }
}else{
    echo "<font style=\"font-size:12px\" color=\"#FFFFFF\" face=\"Century Gothic\">Problems encountered while processing the data ...</font>";
}
?>
```

JS Script:

```
function QueryPrefix()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    var pStr = document.getElementById('Editbox2');
    var htmlHolder = document.getElementById('Html1');
    var butStr = document.getElementById('Button1');

    if (pStr.value.length == 0){
        alert("Please enter a value on the box provided!");
        return; 
    }
    pStr.value="";

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
            {
                htmlHolder.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                butStr.disabled=false;
            }
    }
    butStr.disabled=true;

    xmlhttp.open("POST","searchutype.php",false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("pStr=" + pStr.value);
}
```

Comment: This is probably a better question for stackoverflow or one of the other programming sites.  Why are you setting `pStr.value = ""` and then later trying to use the value in `xmlhttp.send("pStr=" + pStr.value)`?  And, is there a reason you are not using something like jQuery to do this? Might make it a bit easier...although I guess this approach is a bit more lightweight.

Comment: Oh boy. Irrelevant to the issue, but very, VERY important: You have a MASSIVE security hole that can result in having the entire database destroyed. Read up on **SQL injection**. Also, using **Cascading Style Sheets** would make the code much more readable, not to mention reduce the amount of data that needs to be transferred.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing the problem and it seems to work for me, using Chrome as the client and PHP 5.2 on the server. But I did notice that you're not sending the Content-Length header as a header, which may be the problem. Try adding:

```
var post = "pStr=" + pStr.value;
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length",post.length);
```

Of course you're have to URL encode pStr.value as well before posting it. As nickb said earlier, why not just use a library of framework such as jquery?